# (Drupal) Trying to set mouseover images, yet Drupal mangles it with garbage code. How can I resolve this?

Tags: html, image, drupal, tags

Good morning, Stackoverflow! Fairly simple question - I'm trying to set up mouseover images on Drupal, and I provide this again, fairly simple image tag:

```
<img src="http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_n3cril.png" onmouseover=""http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_n3cril_hover.png" onmouseout="http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_n3cril.png">
```

however, when I submit the changes, Drupal mangles it to this:

```
<img onmouseout="this.src=''http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_nanakis.png" onmouseover="this.src=''http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_nanakis_hover.png" src="http://www.gameaether.com/Images/stream_n3cril.png" />
```

NOTE: The 'Nanakis' is another image that I'm trying to do the same to. Same results across the board.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create two function which will be called on respective mouse events and change the image over there!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the input filter you are using. 
For what I know Drupal doesn't alter data when you save it but tries to clean potential xss when showing it.
Consider to use a jQuery method like

```
$('#imageID').hover(function() { $(this).attr('src', 'mouseover img src') }, function() {$(this).attr('src', 'mouseout img src')});
```